# From LabelMe .xml polygon to coco format .json

Tags: json, xml, coco, labelme

I have this kind of labeled polygon type .XML files. how can I convert it to the coco .json segmentation format[This is .XML file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfFqQ.png)

Comment: Did you answer your question?